# How can I filter out a list using another list

Tags: python, list, filter

I've got a list which includes other lists like this:

```
l = [['a book','an owl','a banana'],['a car','an apple','a carrot']]
```

And I've got another list like this:

```
f = [['book','banana'],[['car','apple']]
```

Now what I wanna do is to find the items in l list that contain the words from their counterpart in f list. for example items containing both "book" and "banana" ( from item 1 in f ) in "a book", "an owl" and "a banana" ( from item 1 in l ).
Next step is to append the found items to a new list so the result will end up like this:

```
l_filtered = [['a book','a banana'],['a car','an apple']]
```

I've been trying to do this through the piece of code below but it returns literally nothing back but [a bunch of [ ]'s.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTNJ5.jpg)

Anyway here is the piece of code I wrote :

```
l = [['a book','an owl','a banana'],['a car','an apple','a carrot']]
f = [['book','a'],['car','apple']]
s = []

for item in l:
    eachlist = item
    filtered = []
    for item in f:
        eachmatcherlist = item
        for item in eachmatcherlist:
            eachword = item 
            finder = [s for s in eachlist if eachword in s ]
            filtered.extend(finder)
        s.append(filtered)
        filtered.clear()

print(s)
```

Another issue is I want to append items from l to s which contain both "book" and "a". Hypothetically if my code worked It would return all the items with a **or** book in them but I want items with book and **a**.

I'd really appreciate anyhelp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked on your code a litte:

```
l = [['a book','an owl','a banana'],['a car','an apple','a carrot']]
f = [['book','banana'],['car','apple']]

result = []
for phrases,checks in zip(l,f):
    tmp = []
    for phrase in phrases:
        for check in checks:
            for word in phrase.split():
                if check == word:
                    tmp.append(phrase)
    
    result.append(tmp)
print(result)
```

Results in:

```
[['a book', 'a banana'], ['a car', 'an apple']]
```